# How can I apply this kind of texture to a curve?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, sculpting

I want to block out the hair using curves and use a displace modifier with a cloud texture. I tried doing what this artist did in this video: https://youtu.be/Rm4xWmPk5kE?t=843

I created a curve, shaped it, and converted it into a mesh. I applied a subdivision modifier, then a displacement modifier. I played around with the settings, but I can't get it to look the way it does in the video. It just bloats the mesh. I'm not sure what to do at this point other than block out the hair with curves and sculpt each section by hand.

[image]

Comment: Did you assign the _Voronoi Crackle_ texture he appears to have done, in the Displacement modifier?

Comment: If you post your blend file on blend-exchange.com someone will be able to help you. Hard otherwise!

Comment: I did assign the crackle texture, but some of the curves didn't react well to it. I also uploaded the blend file. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BvS67n0Z" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BvS67n0Z/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

The mesh objects that have been created from the curves have a **non-uniform scale** (e.g. 0.444, 0734, 1.234) as you can see in the viewport's side panel **(1)**. 
 You need to apply the *Scale*. Select the object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode to do this. It will keep the transformation and reset the scale values to 1.0, 1.0, 1.0.

Then tweak the value for the displacement texture a bit so that the mesh will not be turned inside out, see **(2)** and **(3)**. Enable the *Face Orientation* overlay to check the normals.

You can also use a *Remesh* and a *Decimate* modifier to close the tips of the hair strands, **(4)** and **(5)**.

If you want to sculpt the hair don't forget to apply all modifiers.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, Blunder. I'm still feeling my way around Blender and I'm definitely going to keep all this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I got the effect I wanted by shaping a cube with a combination of extrusions, loop cuts, and a subdivision modifier in edit mode. The displacement modifier worked fine after everything was put in place.